# Descubrir el numero mas pequeño de un array Javascript sin Math.min()

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, bucles

Estoy tratando de descubrir como encontrar el numero mas pequeño de un array con un bucle y un concicional. Lo he intentado con `if`, pero no hay manera. Sé que con `Math.min` te da  directamente el valor más bajo.

Sé que es posible construirlo con el condicional `if` o incluso con el `while` pero no hay manera de conseguirlo, no sé que falla en mi código.

```js
var numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];

var min = numeros[0]

for(i=0;i<numeros.length;i++){
    if(min<numeros[i++]){

       (min=numeros[i++])
    }else if (min>numeros[i++]){
        (numeros[i++]=min)
    }else{
        console.log(min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La mejor solución es usar `Math.min()`, como comentan en [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/274004/111983), pero como dices que no lo quieres con `min` aquí va con tu código.

Hay varios problemas en tu código. Cada vez que haces `i++`, estás aumentando el valor de `i`, por lo que acabas saltándote índices.

Luego tu lógica de `if-else` no tiene mucho sentido. Lo único que necesitas es saber si el elemento por el que estás iterando es menor que `min` iteración. Es decir `numeros[i] < min`, en cuyo caso, actualizas el valor de `min` al elemento que toca comparar.

Tu código correcto sería (he cambiado el array y he añadido un log más en el if para que veas cómo funciona):

```js
var numeros = [ 67, 6, 23, 11, 100, 8, 3, 93, 0, 17, 24, 7, -2, 33, 45, 28, 33, 23, -12, 99, 100 ];

var min = numeros[0];

for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length ; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] < min) {
        console.log('Anterior minimo: ' + min + ', nuevo minimo: ' + numeros[i]);
        min = numeros[i];
    }
}
console.log('Valor mínimo: ' + min);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me sirvio de mucho, entendi bien mi error y el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 3):

UNa forma muy sencilla es usar el metodo min() de la clase Math

```js
var numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];

var min = Math.min(...numeros) 
console.log(min)
```

fuente [aquí](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/calculate-the-max-min-value-from-an-array/)

Comment: El OP ya ha comentado que conoce esta solución, pero está intentando algo *más manual*

Answer (score 2):

Espero te sirva esto, suerte!

```js
var numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];

var min = numeros[0]; //El minimo por el momento es el primer elemento de nuestro array

for(i=1;i<numeros.length;i++){  //empezamos desde la 2da posicion ya que el primero se deduce ser el menor hasta el momento 
    if(numeros[i]<min){   //preguntamos si el proximo elemento de nuestro array (posicion i) es menor que el min
       (min=numeros[i])   // si se cumple la condicion reemplazamos el valor de min por el valor que se encuentra en nuestro array en la posicion i 
    }
}
console.log(min); //una vez finalizado el recorrido y encontrado el menor valor lo mostramos por pantalla


// OTRA OPCION CON FOREACH (buble que recorre TODO el Array sin necesidad de saber la longitud del mismo)
numeros.forEach(numero => {
    if(numero<min){  
        (min=numero)   
     }
    
});
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un simple ciclo for:

```
//Inicializas menor para que no tengas que recorrer todo el arreglo
var menor = numeros[0];
for (i=1; i<numeros.length; i++) {
 // Si el numero actual de la iteración es menor que el numero almacenado en la variable menor...
 if(numeros[i] < menor){
   //Actualizo el valor de la variable menor
   menor = numeros[i];
 }
}
```

O puedes explotar las funciones que vienen con los arreglos como `reduce`:

```
var menor = numeros.reduce(function(menor, numero) {
    if(menor > numero) {
       menor = numero;
    }
    return menor;
}, numeros[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a ver tu código:

```js
var numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];

var min = numeros[0]; //nos quedamos con el primer número del array, OK

for(let i=0; i < numeros.length; i++) { //recorremos el array, OK
    
    if(min<numeros[i++]){ //Si el valor del array es mayor que min...

       (min=numeros[i++]) //... nos quedamos con el mayor de los dos? No OK
       
    }else if (min>numeros[i++]){ //si min es mayor ...
        (numeros[i++]=min) // ... Lo ponemos en el array? no OK
    }else{
        console.log(min); //Si estamos aquí es que es igual a lo que tenemos?
    }
}
```

Ahora arreglemos esto:

```js
const numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];

let min = numeros[0]; //nos quedamos con el primer número del array, OK

for(let i=0; i < numeros.length; i++) { //recorremos el array, OK
    
  if (min > numeros[i]) {
    min=numeros[i]; // nuevo mínimo encontrado, nos quedamos con él
  }
}

console.log('El menor es',min);
```

Como puedes ver, es más sencillo de lo que estabas intentando.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numeros = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,2,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];
var resultado=numeros.find(num=>num<100);
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Explica tu codigo para que en caso de que haya algo que no se entiende pueda aclararse la duda.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

En el código, guardamos el último elemento del array dada en la variable mínimo y lo comparamos con el elemento anterior. Si el elemento es menor que la variable mínimo, almacenaremos este elemento en la variable mínimo. Y si no, pasaremos al siguiente elemento. Repetiremos este procedimiento hasta llegar al índice 0. Tras el bucle, devolveremos la variable mínimo.

```js
function MyMin(myarr){
    var al = myarr.length;
    minimum = myarr[al-1];
    while (al--){
        if(myarr[al] < minimum){
            minimum = myarr[al]
        }
    }
    return minimum;
};
var myArray = [1, 5, 6, 2, 3];
var m = MyMin(myArray);
console.log(m)
```